# Creating a filename from variable

Tags: python, file

I have a filename named *hosts_access_log_00.txt* that I take in from user input like 
    `filename = input()`

I need to write some output to another filename called *records_host_access_log_00.txt* where the *host_access_log_00.txt* comes from `filename`.

How can I create this filename with this specific name? (i.e. prepending "records" to the `filename`)

Answer (score 0):

Just string format would be helpful.

`'records_%s' % filename`

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work.

Comment: Or just plain concatenation, since they're both strings already: `'records_' + filename`.

Comment: @KrithikaRaghavendran: "Doesn't work" is the least helpful possible comment. If it doesn't work, tell us how it fails. Tell us what you expected, what you got, including tracebacks if you got an exception. Edit this into your question; if your problem is "my code doesn't work", you need to provide a [MCVE], so we're not just guessing at what you're trying to do and failing.